# Get Activity's widget from service

Tags: java, android, service, android-activity

The main activity has an AlarmManager which calls a Service every X minutes. I need a way that the methods inside the service's class can update a TextView in the main activity, but I dont know how to get the TextView's object in the service. Is there any way?

Here is part of the code:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyAlarmService.class);
pintent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 60000, pintent);
```

Answer (score 0):

In  your alarm service you have a onReceive method

```
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {

        String data = "haha";
        if (data.isEmpty() == false && data.contentEquals("") == false) {

            nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            CharSequence from = "sing";
            CharSequence message = data;
                   //get the activity
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                    new Intent(), 0);
            Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
                    data, System.currentTimeMillis());
            notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
            nm.notify(1, notif);

        }
```

Method call:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReminderReceiverActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
                100000, pendingIntent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need, in an accelerometer-reading service and an app that would start/stop the service and display the current average accelerometer magnitude.

I used Service Binding to allow the Service to send a Message to the Activity, containing the accelerometer value.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger for background on Binding.  For a good example, see the API Samples' MessengerServiceActivities and MessengerService classes.

I did the following.  I've left out the mundane details (such as Synchronization to avoid races) for clarity. Notice that I use bind() as well as StartService().  The bind() is for sending messages between the Activity and Service; the StartService() is so the Service keeps running after the Activity exits.

Basically, the Activity and Service exchange Messengers that will allow each to send Messages to the other.  The Activity sends custom Messages to the Service in order to Subscribe to Service Messages or Unsubscribe from Service Messsages.  When the Service wants to send data to the Activity, it sends a custom Message to the Activity's Messenger.  The Activity, on receiving such a message, displays the new value to the user.

The answer that suggested using Notifications uses a simple way to get data onto the screen.  This more complex Message-passing answer is needed if you want to display data in your Activity (vs. the Notification bar).

I apologize for the length of the example code below, but there are a lot of necessary details to convey.

In my Activity, named AccelServiceControl:

```
private FromServiceHandler handler;  // My custom class for Handling Messages from my Service.
private Messenger fromService;  // For receiving messages from our Service
...
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    handler = new FromServiceHandler(this);
    fromService = new Messenger(handler);
    ...
}
protected void onResume() {
    ...
    // While we're in the foreground, we want to be bound to our service.
    // onServiceConnected() will return the IBinder we'll use to communicate back and forth.
    bindService(new Intent(this, AccelService.class), this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
protected void onPause() {
    ...
    // Note: By itself, this doesn't stop the Service from sending messages to us.
    // We need to send a custom Unsubscribe Message to stop getting messages from the Service.
    unbindService(this);

}
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Send a custom intent to start or stop our Service.
    if (buttonStart == v) {
        startService(new Intent(AccelService.ACTION_START));
    } else if (buttonStop == v) {
        startService(new Intent(AccelService.ACTION_STOP));
    }
    ...
}
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
    ...
    // Ask our Service to send us updates.
    toService = new Messenger(service);
    Message msg = Message.obtain(null, FromClientHandler.MSG_SUBSCRIBE);    // our custom Subscribe message
    msg.replyTo = fromService;
    try {
        toService.send(msg);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // Failed because the Service has died.
        // We handle this in onServiceDisconnected().
    }
}
```

In the Activity's custom Message Handler:

```
....
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    switch (msg.what) {
    case MSG_ACCEL_UPDATE:
        ...
        Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
        double accelValue = bundle.getDouble(ACCEL_UPDATE_VALUE);
        ...then display the new accelValue in, for example, a TextView.
    ...
    }
}
```

In the Service, named AccelService:

```
...
private Messenger fromClient;   // For receiving messages from our Client(s).
private FromClientHandler handler;      // needed just for unlinking at in onDestroy().
// Since we have only one Client, we store only one Activity's Messenger
private Messenger subscribedMessenger;
public void onCreate() {
    ...
    handler = new FromClientHandler(this);
    fromClient = new Messenger(handler);
}
public void onDestroy() {
    // Unlink ourselves from our Handler, so the Garbage Collector can get rid of us.  That's a topic in itself.
    handler.unlink();
    ....
}
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    ...
    int returnValue = START_NOT_STICKY;
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (ACTION_START.equals(action)) {
        doActionStart();
        returnValue = START_STICKY;
    } else if (ACTION_STOP.equals(action)) {
        ...
        // Our Service is done
        stopSelf();
    }
    ... 
    return returnValue;
}
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // Hand back a way to send messages to us.
    return fromClient.getBinder();
}
...when we want to send data to the Activity:
    Message msg = Message.obtain(null, FromServiceHandler.MSG_ACCEL_UPDATE);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putDouble(FromServiceHandler.ACCEL_UPDATE_VALUE,  avgAccel);
    msg.setData(bundle);
    try {
        subscribedMessenger.send(msg);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // Failed because the Client has unbound.
        subscribedMessenger = null;
    }
```